# StreamReader.ReadLine throwing a strange ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I'm using a `StreamReader` on a large text-file (~300 MB) and calling ReadLine() in a loop eventually throws a weird `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
Index and count must refer to a location within the buffer.
Parameter name: bytes
```

The stacktrace is:

```
at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount,
Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Boolean flush)
at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount,
Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
....
```

Is this some weird memory error? It doesn't throw `OutOfMemoryException` so I'm a bit lost.
It happens around the 2000th line. By that time, even if it continues with a successful ReadLine(), it starts throwing weird exceptions elsewhere. So there's a probably memory leak somewhere, but is there anything specific to `ReadLine()` or `StreamReader` to look at?

Each line in my text file is exactly 24 characters long.

Comment: It might be an error somewhere else in your code, post the code that is calling `ReadLine`...

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is specific to StremReader.ReadLine() it may be:

- the number of characters in the next line is larger than Int32.MaxValue
- the buffer you passed to StremReader constructor is too small

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the file should be larger than ~2 GB?

Comment: but the OP states that file is ~300 MB (might be incorrect, of course).

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic it could be or the line larger than int32.maxvalue or the buffer is too small. Or he found a bug in the framework.. We'll never know if he does not put the code...